# Powershell Profile not Generating

Tags: powershell

I've been developing in Debian Linux for years, but recently I've had to switch to a windows environment for my new job. There are a number of .exe programs I need to run daily, so I would like to make permanent aliases for them in a local PowerShell profile. I went to set up a PowerShell profile following instruction on [LazyAdmin.com](https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/powershell-profile/) when I hit this problem.

I ran this command in PowerShell (session running as full admin):

```
New-Item -Path $profile -Type File -Force
```

When I got the error:

```
New-Item : Could not find file 'C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -Path $profile -Type File -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\MyPC...ell_profile.ps1:String) [New-Item], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

In File Explorer I can navigate to my Documents\WindowsPowerShell\ folder and open it. It is currently empty, thus the need to make a profile.ps1. Vim and Notepad (ran as admins) each are unable to ":wq", and "Save As" to this location even after creating a new file. I get the error:

`File not found. Check the file name and try again.`

Thoughts?

Comment: Is it the same Admin account credentials you used to log into the computer? Seems to point to a permissions issue. Does running the same command on a non-elevated  Shell give you the same error?

Comment: Yep. Same admin account credentials as the rest of my computer.

Comment: Your account is MyPC?  You are logged in to a different account so unless you are an admin you cannot read the MyPC folder.  If you can read the file from an explorer than you are using Admin.  The you have to start PS by right click the shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: No, my account name is actually my full name. I just changed it for the sake of displaying it on a public forum.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, I just tested creating a profile while not an admin, and I get the same errors. Could it be that I somehow don't have correct security access on my own PC? Vim and Visual Studios run as admin all the time with no issues...???

Comment: Check the folder permissions to see who has modify access and if possible change that so you get control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several weeks of this issue I just solved the problem!

I went in to File Explorer and navigated to "C:\Users[my name]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell" and created the file "Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1" in notepad by:

```
Right mouse click - New - Text Document
```

and after editing I "Saved As" in that folder.

This still threw an error as always, but this time I followed [Learn.Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3)'s instructions to change my local PowerShell execution policies by running in PowerShell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

While this opens up a potential security risk if a hacker got a session with elevated privileges and used it to run a malicious script on my machine, I am very careful on what I allow to be installed and give privileges to in the first place, so along with my firewall and Windows Defender I shouldn't ever have an issue with this.